# Find $g’(0)$ when $f(0) = 2$ and $f’(0) = 3$ (SFU Mathematics 180)

Tags: calculus

Let $g(x) = f (2 - f(x))^2$ where $f(0)=2$ and and $f’(0) = 3$. Find $g’(0)$, simplifying your answer completely.

I have no clue where to start. I’ve tried to differentiate $g(x)$ but I’m pretty sure I’m not doing it right...

This is what I have done so far:

$g’(x) = 2 f(2-f(x)) • -f’(x)$

$g’(0)= 2 f(2-f(0)) • -f’(0)$

$= 2 f(2-2) • -3$

$= 2 f(0) • -3$

$= 2 f(0) • -3$

$= 2 • 2 • -3$

$= -12$

Edit: seems like I gotta review the chain rule xD

Comment: Hi. Please give context to the problem as well as any attempts you made at solving it.

Comment: $$g'(x) = -2\cdot f(2-f(x))\cdot f'(2-f(x))\cdot f'(x)$$$$g'(0)=-2\cdot f(2-2)\cdot f'(2-2)\cdot f'(0)=-2\cdot f(0)\cdot f'(0)^2=-36$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the chain rule on $g(x)$. Working from the outside in, your problem is
$$g(x) = f(2-f(x))^2$$
First differentiate $j(x) = x^2 \implies j'(x) = 2x$. Also, $j(x) = h(x) \implies j'(x) = h'(x)$ and $j(x) = 2-h(x) \implies j'(x) = -h'(x)$
$$g'(x) = \Big(2f(2-f(x))\Big)\Big(f'(2-f(x))\Big)\Big(-f'(x)\Big)$$
$$=-2f(2-f(x))f'(2-f(x))f'(x)$$
Now, you provided that $f(0) = 2$ and $f'(0) = 3$. So
$$g'(0) = -2f(2-2)f'(2-2)3$$
$$=-6f(0)f'(0)$$
$$=-6*2*3 = -36$$

Comment: thank you so much! i guess i was close but didn’t get the chain rule down D: